# How to do retain names in aggregate by variables

Tags: r

Here example and self-explanatory case with the desired solution:

```
 set.seed(123)
 df <- data.frame(s=rnorm(100), g1=seq(1,100,,100),g2=seq(5,100,,100),g3=seq(10,1,,100))
 agg <- with(df, aggregate(s, data.frame(g1,g2,g3), 
                 FUN = function(x) c("mean" = mean(x), "median" = median(x))))
 head(agg,5)

       g1        g2       g3     x.mean   x.median
1 100 100.00000 1.000000 -1.0264209 -1.0264209
2  99  99.04040 1.090909 -0.2357004 -0.2357004
3  98  98.08081 1.181818  1.5326106  1.5326106
4  97  97.12121 1.272727  2.1873330  2.1873330
5  96  96.16162 1.363636 -0.6002596 -0.6002596
```

Desired results (the -xxx are just the numerical values calculated or each by group):

```
  g1   g2       g3        g1.x.mean  g1.x.median g2.x.mean  g2.x.median g3.x.mean  g3.x.median
1 100 100.00000 1.000000 -1.0264209 -1.0264209   -xxx       -xxxx        -xxxx       -xxxx
2  99  99.04040 1.090909 -0.2357004 -0.2357004   -xxx       -xxxx        -xxxx       -xxxx
3  98  98.08081 1.181818  1.5326106  1.5326106   -xxx       -xxxx        -xxxx       -xxxx
4  97  97.12121 1.272727  2.1873330  2.1873330   -xxx       -xxxx        -xxxx       -xxxx
5  96  96.16162 1.363636 -0.6002596 -0.6002596   -xxx       -xxxx        -xxxx       -xxxx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the grouping should be separate, we can use `lapply` to loop over the 'g' columns, apply the `aggregate` separately and combine them with `cbind`

```
nm1 <- paste0('g', 1:3)
out1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(nm1, function(g)       {
   out <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(s ~ .,  df[c('s', g)],
        FUN = function(x) c(mean(x), median(x))))
    names(out)[-1] <- paste0(g, c('.x.mean', '.x.median'))
   out}))

 out1 <-  out1[c(nm1, setdiff(names(out1), nm1))]
```

-output

```
head(out1)
#  g1       g2       g3   g1.x.mean g1.x.median   g2.x.mean g2.x.median  g3.x.mean g3.x.median
#1  1 5.000000 1.000000 -0.56047565 -0.56047565 -0.56047565 -0.56047565 -1.0264209  -1.0264209
#2  2 5.959596 1.090909 -0.23017749 -0.23017749 -0.23017749 -0.23017749 -0.2357004  -0.2357004
#3  3 6.919192 1.181818  1.55870831  1.55870831  1.55870831  1.55870831  1.5326106   1.5326106
#4  4 7.878788 1.272727  0.07050839  0.07050839  0.07050839  0.07050839  2.1873330   2.1873330
#5  5 8.838384 1.363636  0.12928774  0.12928774  0.12928774  0.12928774 -0.6002596  -0.6002596
#6  6 9.797980 1.454545  1.71506499  1.71506499  1.71506499  1.71506499  1.3606524   1.3606524
```

---

Or as mentioned in the `tidyverse`, if the number of `unique` groups are not same for each of them, an approach is with `ave` to create columns and then apply `unique`

```
out1 <- unique(cbind(df[nm1], do.call(cbind, lapply(nm1, function(g) {
                 mean <- with(df, ave(s, df[[g]]))
                 median <- with(df, ave(s, df[[g]], FUN = median))
                 setNames(data.frame(mean, median),
                       paste0(g, c('.x.mean', '.x.median')))
                       
                       }))))
```

-output

```
head(out1)
#  g1       g2        g3   g1.x.mean g1.x.median   g2.x.mean g2.x.median   g3.x.mean g3.x.median
#1  1 5.000000 10.000000 -0.56047565 -0.56047565 -0.56047565 -0.56047565 -0.56047565 -0.56047565
#2  2 5.959596  9.909091 -0.23017749 -0.23017749 -0.23017749 -0.23017749 -0.23017749 -0.23017749
#3  3 6.919192  9.818182  1.55870831  1.55870831  1.55870831  1.55870831  1.55870831  1.55870831
#4  4 7.878788  9.727273  0.07050839  0.07050839  0.07050839  0.07050839  0.07050839  0.07050839
#5  5 8.838384  9.636364  0.12928774  0.12928774  0.12928774  0.12928774  0.12928774  0.12928774
#6  6 9.797980  9.545455  1.71506499  1.71506499  1.71506499  1.71506499  1.71506499  1.71506499
```

---

Or using `tidyerse`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.0
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfc(nm1, ~ df %>% 
      group_by(across(all_of(.x))) %>%
      summarise(!! str_c(.x, ".x.mean") := mean(s),
        !! str_c(.x, ".x.median") := median(s), .groups = 'drop')) %>% 
    select(all_of(nm1), everything())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 9
#      g1    g2    g3 g1.x.mean g1.x.median g2.x.mean g2.x.median g3.x.mean g3.x.median
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     1  5     1      -0.560      -0.560    -0.560      -0.560     -1.03       -1.03 
# 2     2  5.96  1.09   -0.230      -0.230    -0.230      -0.230     -0.236      -0.236
# 3     3  6.92  1.18    1.56        1.56      1.56        1.56       1.53        1.53 
# 4     4  7.88  1.27    0.0705      0.0705    0.0705      0.0705     2.19        2.19 
# 5     5  8.84  1.36    0.129       0.129     0.129       0.129     -0.600      -0.600
# 6     6  9.80  1.45    1.72        1.72      1.72        1.72       1.36        1.36 
# 7     7 10.8   1.55    0.461       0.461     0.461       0.461     -0.628      -0.628
# 8     8 11.7   1.64   -1.27       -1.27     -1.27       -1.27       0.239       0.239
# 9     9 12.7   1.73   -0.687      -0.687    -0.687      -0.687      0.548       0.548
#10    10 13.6   1.82   -0.446      -0.446    -0.446      -0.446      0.994       0.994
# … with 90 more rows
```

---

If the grouping columns have different number of unique elements, an option would be to `mutate/transmute` new columns and then take the `distinct` at the end

```
map_dfc(nm1, ~ df %>% 
      group_by(across(all_of(.x))) %>%
      transmute(!! str_c(.x, ".x.mean") := mean(s),
        !! str_c(.x, ".x.median") := median(s))) %>% 
    select(all_of(nm1), everything()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    distinct
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 9
#      g1    g2    g3 g1.x.mean g1.x.median g2.x.mean g2.x.median g3.x.mean g3.x.median
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     1  5    10      -0.560      -0.560    -0.560      -0.560    -0.560      -0.560 
# 2     2  5.96  9.91   -0.230      -0.230    -0.230      -0.230    -0.230      -0.230 
# 3     3  6.92  9.82    1.56        1.56      1.56        1.56      1.56        1.56  
# 4     4  7.88  9.73    0.0705      0.0705    0.0705      0.0705    0.0705      0.0705
# 5     5  8.84  9.64    0.129       0.129     0.129       0.129     0.129       0.129 
# 6     6  9.80  9.55    1.72        1.72      1.72        1.72      1.72        1.72  
# 7     7 10.8   9.45    0.461       0.461     0.461       0.461     0.461       0.461 
# 8     8 11.7   9.36   -1.27       -1.27     -1.27       -1.27     -1.27       -1.27  
# 9     9 12.7   9.27   -0.687      -0.687    -0.687      -0.687    -0.687      -0.687 
#10    10 13.6   9.18   -0.446      -0.446    -0.446      -0.446    -0.446      -0.446 
# … with 90 more rows
```

Comment: blame me, so obvious yet I felt to see it. thanks!

Comment: sorry, but this is misunderstanding, I get now the mean, median of the variables, but I want mean, median of "s" per groups g1  g2  g3!

Comment: well, but this gives the result I already provide in my example...

Comment: @Maximilian so you want to do the grouping separately, instead of a single group?

Comment: well, I think the 'desired result` is clear, I want to have calculated mean, median of "s" per each group =g1,g2,g3, basically a mean, median of the random variable here in this example, for each group, g1-g3.

Comment: @Maximilian You need to do the grouping separately as `aggregate`combines all  of them together in a single call

Comment: clear, can you please erase your solution and provide minimalist solution?

Comment: @Maximilian sorry, I earlier misunderstood your question.  I updated the solutions.  Hope it helps. thanks

Comment: @Maximilian I would say this approach about binding together all list elements work as long as the number of unique groups are the same for each of the 'g' columns

Comment: exactly, and the 'g' groups are not unique! Hence it does not work, it works on the example but not on real data. Each group has fewer rows once the example is calculated, can you perhaps extend your answer such the it gives NA if the result is shorter?

Comment: @Maximilian I guess you may need to frame the logic differently because this would never work

Comment: @Maximilian Or a possible option with `tidyverse` approach is `instead of `summarise`, use `mutate` so that it creates new columns, and then take the `distinct` of the relevant columns

Comment: @Maximilian I think the updated one with `transmute` would work for those cases

Comment: hmm, I prefer to use only core R functions, I will figure this out. many thanks. I was seeking solution within `aggregate` that this would work, but as you confirm this is not possible.

Comment: @Maximilian if you want only `base R`, then `ave` is an option

Comment: I know `ave` but this would take me long time to figure out, I'm weak on `ave` can you show me how, please? Many thanks.

Comment: I'm very sorry for bothering so much...I will take it from here, many thanks again for your help! But if you still find time to show with `ave` this would be great. thanks.

Comment: @Maximilian it is now updated. thanks for the patience

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% group_by(s) %>%
  summarise_all(.funs = list("x.mean"=mean,"x.median"=median))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 7
       s g1_x.mean g2_x.mean g3_x.mean g1_x.median g2_x.median g3_x.median
   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 -2.31        72      73.1      3.55          72        73.1        3.55
 2 -1.97        18      21.3      8.45          18        21.3        8.45
 3 -1.69        26      29.0      7.73          26        29.0        7.73
 4 -1.55        57      58.7      4.91          57        58.7        4.91
 5 -1.27        43      45.3      6.18          43        45.3        6.18
 6 -1.27         8      11.7      9.36           8        11.7        9.36
 7 -1.22        78      78.9      3             78        78.9        3   
 8 -1.14        29      31.9      7.45          29        31.9        7.45
 9 -1.12        46      48.2      5.91          46        48.2        5.91
10 -1.07        65      66.4      4.18          65        66.4        4.18
# ... with 90 more rows
```